# start and stop node.js script automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file

Is there any solution to start and stop a node.js script **without using command prompt** on Windows machine? I mean by using a script to start and stop the node.js server (without the need to the command prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nodemon. it will  give you the power to auto restart your server after the file change Done.

npm install -g nodemon

after installation just use nodemon instead of node to run your file.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple problem with your query: how do you launch the script to stop your Node.js process without a prompt?

An option which will most likely fit your needs is to use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). PM2 is a process manager in which you can start, restart, stop, etc. Node.js processes.

You can start your script with `pm2 start PATH_TO_SCRIPT -n IDENTIFICATION_NAME`, then stop it with `pm2 stop IDENTIFICATION_NAME` or restart it with `pm2 restart IDENTIFICATION_NAME`.

If you want to simplify the process or have an icon to double-click on to manage your Node.js script, you could execute the above commands in a Batch script.

---

PM2 also has a Web service, [Keymetrics](https://keymetrics.io/), to manage processes remotely (via a Web interface).

Hope it helps!